# Linq query to select items in list from another list

Tags: linq

I have a dictionary and a list.

```
AllMeta: is a dictionary<string, WikiMeta>

Meta: is a list<WikiMeta>

public class WikiMeta
{
    public string ContentTitle { get; set; }
    public string PageTitle { get; set; }
    public string PageMetaDescription { get; set; }
    public List<WikiArticle> Articles = new List<WikiArticle>();
    public List<WikiGroup> Groups = new List<WikiGroup>();
}

public class WikiGroup
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I need to select values from AllMeta where AllMeta.Values.Group == Meta.Group returning a list of WikiMeta.

However, I'm struggling to construct the syntax (lambda), so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
List<WikiMeta> wikis= AllMeta.Values
                             .Where(allmeta => 
                              Meta.Any(meta=> meta.Group == allmeta.Group))
                             .ToList();
```

where I've assumed following:

```
public class WikiMeta
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Group { get; set; }
}

public IDictionary<string,WikiMeta> AllMeta { get; set; }
public List<WikiMeta> Meta { get; set; }
```

make sure you referenced `System.Linq` namespace i.e.

```
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Manish. I missed out that a WikiMeta can have multiple groups and is therefore a list.